# Logback sift RollingFileAppender not rotating when run from WAR

Tags: java, logback

I have a logback config that logs to multiple files including the primary log file called servernexus.log.  Each log file is suppose to be rotated by RollingFileAppender.  When I run from eclipse with the logback config file and everything else in my $CLASSPATH the servernexus.log is rotated properly by logback.  When I run from my production WAR file logging works but the servernexus.log rotation never happens.

Here's the logback-server-win32event.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="SiftAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>discriminatorId</key>
            <defaultValue>${cmb.log.file.name}</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${discriminatorId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>${cmb.log.dir}/${discriminatorId}.log</file>
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- daily rollover -->
                    <fileNamePattern>${cmb.log.dir}/archive/${discriminatorId}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
                    <!-- keep ${maxbackupindex} days' worth of history capped at ${maxfilesize} total size -->
                    <maxHistory>${cmb.log.maxbackupindex}</maxHistory>
                    <totalSizeCap>${cmb.log.maxfilesize}</totalSizeCap>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.id" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.cfg.annotations" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- DEBUG output shows db user password:  -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- DEBUG output shows db user password:  -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.mchange" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.quartz" level="INFO"/>
    <!-- HtmlUnit - turn off debug by debug -->
    <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.eclipse" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- Disable "WARN XXX scanned from multiple locations" -->
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser" level="ERROR"/>
    <if condition='isDefined("logging.jetty.level")'>
        <then>
            <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="${logging.jetty.level}"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO"/>
        </else>
    </if>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="SiftAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

As you can see I'm using a discriminator which is set as a system property at runtime prior to logback being initialized.  You can see the "cmb.log.file.name" property in the output below.

When I run from eclipse it works and reports the expected TimeBasedRollingPolicy lines:

```
11:19:40,144 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.file = C:\Users\mcooper\ws\cmb\6.0\run\server\log\servernexus.log
11:19:40,194 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Configuring log to file for logback var "log.file.name" = "servernexus"
11:19:40,194 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.file.name = servernexus
11:19:40,194 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.maxfilesize = 50MB
11:19:40,194 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.maxbackupindex = 5
11:19:40,303 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-server-win32event.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/mcooper/ws/cmb/6.0/CmbProduct/Common/bin/main/logback-server-win32event.xml]
11:19:40,440 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender]
11:19:40,455 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SiftAppender]
11:19:40,478 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator] for [discriminator] property
11:19:40,493 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.mangogrove.logbackwela.Win32EventLogAppender]
11:19:40,496 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [EventLogAppender]
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache] to WARN
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to INFO
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.type] to ERROR
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.id] to ERROR
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations] to WARN
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl] to WARN
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] to WARN
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] to WARN
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.mchange] to INFO
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to WARN
11:19:40,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.quartz] to INFO
11:19:40,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit] to INFO
11:19:40,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse] to WARN
11:19:40,872 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.jetty] to INFO
11:19:40,872 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
11:19:40,872 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SiftAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
11:19:40,873 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [EventLogAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
11:19:40,873 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:19:40,878 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@64485a47 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
2020-09-01 11:19:40.952:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1106ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
11:19:40,979 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
11:19:40,985 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE-servernexus]
11:19:40,993 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@2076287037 - setting totalSizeCap to 50 MB
11:19:41,015 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@2076287037 - Will use gz compression
11:19:41,017 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@2076287037 - Will use the pattern C:/Users/mcooper/ws/cmb/6.0/run/server/log/archive/servernexus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
11:19:41,024 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'C:/Users/mcooper/ws/cmb/6.0/run/server/log/archive/servernexus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz'.
11:19:41,024 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
11:19:41,026 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Tue Sep 01 11:17:12 PDT 2020
11:19:41,028 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:19:41,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE-servernexus] - Active log file name: C:\Users\mcooper\ws\cmb\6.0\run\server\log/servernexus.log
11:19:41,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE-servernexus] - File property is set to [C:\Users\mcooper\ws\cmb\6.0\run\server\log/servernexus.log]
```

When I run from production WAR file the logback output does not report anything for TimeBasedRollingPolicy:

```
10:55:10,673 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.dir = C:\ProgramData\XXX\YYY\log
10:55:10,673 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.file = C:\ProgramData\XXX\YYY\log\servernexus.log
10:55:10,767 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Configuring log to file for logback var "log.file.name" = "servernexus"
10:55:10,767 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.file.name = servernexus
10:55:10,767 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.maxfilesize = 50MB
10:55:10,767 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging PROP cmb.log.maxbackupindex = 5
10:55:10,782 INFO  Log Configurator                                   T1  | Logging [servernexus.log] to C:\ProgramData\XXX\YYY\log\servernexus.log using logback-server-win32event.xml
2020-09-01 10:55:12.236:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1792ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/s-cmbtest/AppData/Local/Temp/yyy_console_wartmp_6.0.79/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/XXX/YYY/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
10:55:59,322 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-server-win32event.xml] at [jar:file:/C:/Users/s-cmbtest/AppData/Local/Temp/yyy_console_wartmp_6.0.79/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Common-6.0.79.jar!/logback-server-win32event.xml]
10:55:59,322 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-server-win32event.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
10:55:59,322 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-server-win32event.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/s-cmbtest/AppData/Local/Temp/yyy_console_wartmp_6.0.79/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Common-6.0.79.jar!/logback-server-win32event.xml]
10:55:59,322 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-server-win32event.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/XXX/YYY/lib/Common-6.0.79.jar!/logback-server-win32event.xml]
10:55:59,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1f05b63d - URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/s-cmbtest/AppData/Local/Temp/yyy_console_wartmp_6.0.79/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Common-6.0.79.jar!/logback-server-win32event.xml] is not of type file
10:55:59,448 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
10:55:59,448 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender]
10:55:59,448 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SiftAppender]
10:55:59,463 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator] for [discriminator] property
10:55:59,463 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.mangogrove.logbackwela.Win32EventLogAppender]
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [EventLogAppender]
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache] to WARN
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to INFO
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.type] to ERROR
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.id] to ERROR
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations] to WARN
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl] to WARN
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] to WARN
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] to WARN
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.mchange] to INFO
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to WARN
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.quartz] to INFO
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit] to INFO
10:55:59,479 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse] to WARN
10:55:59,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.jetty] to INFO
10:55:59,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
10:55:59,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SiftAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
10:55:59,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [EventLogAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
10:55:59,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
10:55:59,775 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@524b1c70 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Comment: Quick question, what happens if we remove logback.xml from eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  The logback, slf4j, etc classes where being loaded twice by jetty.  The fix was to tell jetty to treat these classes as system classes:

```
WebAppContext.addSystemClasses(server, "org.slf4j.", "ch.qos.logback.", "org.apache.commons.logging.", "org.apache.log4j.", "org.codehaus.janino.");
```

So simple right? :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert of this but here is what I think should help find the issue. Enable debug in the configuration to check logback and you are missing the %i . From the Chapter 4 of the Appenders in logback documentation

"Note the "%i" conversion token in addition to "%d". Both the %i and %d tokens are mandatory. Each time the current log file reaches maxFileSize before the current time period ends, it will be archived with an increasing index, starting at 0."

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm using TimeBasedRollingPolicy which does not require %i.  The SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy does require %d and %i which is what I think you saw.